# LatchCountdown fails on Platform.runLater task

Tags: java, javafx

I want to visualize my Heap sort algorithm using JavaFX, after each swap of the elements in my array, I also swap the values of the two corresponding `bars` in a `barChart`. The algorithm works fine, but when updating the GUI the `runnable` doesn't seem to block the next runnable for it's execution.

**That's why my graph is messed up (values aren't swapped in order). See image below:** 
[image: "Sorted array"]

**Here is my runnable code snippet:**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Await");
                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
                // queuing the done notification into the javafx thread
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        controller.updateChart(parentIndex, childIndex);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

The latch is declared as class variable, and not modified somewhere else:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

**here the code snippet the runnable is doing:**

```
@Override
public void updateChart(int index1, int index2) {

    Object tempObject = series.getData().get(index2);
    series.getData().set(index2, series.getData().get(index1));
    series.getData().set(index1, tempObject);
    barChartCopy.getData().setAll(series);
}
```

**Any idea, why the latch isn't  considered?**

Comment: We have no way of knowing without seeing how you modify the latch elsewhere.

Comment: I declared the latch as class variable (see updated code)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: You never call `countDown()` form the code you show. Furthermore even if the code inside the `Runnable` passed to `runLater` did call the method on the `CountDownLatch`, the thread would wait forever, since the logic triggering the `countDown` call is not scheduled at the time you start waiting... Assuming multiple of these runnables decrement the same latch, this could also be problematic...

Comment: So where should I add the countdown @fabian

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Pause the sorting algorithm until the GUI was notified of the change?

Comment: Exactly, swap the array then the bars on the Gui and then continue sorting @fabian

Comment: It's probably much simpler to calculate all the changes to the GUI before making any changes: Simply create a list where each element stores one set of values the GUI requires. Then use e.g. a `Timeline` to display the changes one by one. This way you get rid of multithreading completely (as your code is concerned) and it shouldn't make a difference in performance for reasonably small inputs...

Comment: Never done that, sorry for my noobish approaches but how  would you do that?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573747/dynamic-bar-chart-in-java-fx/53579013#53579013