# I want to input values to be plotted on a scatter plot graph

Tags: java, javafx, graph, jfreechart, jfreechart-fx

I would like to create an application in Java I can use to plot points onto a scatterplot. I'm using the JFreeChart external library for this. I've tried creating a text.box to input the values, however it wont let me use the variable in different methods could someone please help me it'd be greatly appreciated.

```
package Grava;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.statistics.HistogramDataset;
import org.jfree.chart.fx.ChartViewer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtils;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.statistics.HistogramDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends graph{
    static Stage window;
    Stage window1;
    Button button;
    Button exitButton;
    Button button1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Grava");
        Image image = new Image("Grava.logo.png");
        window.getIcons().add(image);

        String arr[] = {"Voltage", "Current", ""};
        /*
        Integer yVariables[] = {4, 6, 8, 10};
        Integer xVariables[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        Integer deltaY = ((yVariables[(yVariables.length - 1)]) - (yVariables[0]));
        Integer deltaX = ((xVariables[(xVariables.length - 1)]) - (xVariables[0]));
        Integer gradient = ((deltaY) / (deltaX));
        */
        ChoiceBox dropDown = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(arr));
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 100));
        grid.setVgap(8);

        TextField passInput = new TextField();
        passInput.setPromptText("password");
        GridPane.setConstraints(passInput, 1, 0);

        TextField Xbox1 = new TextField();
        passInput.setPromptText("password");
        GridPane.setConstraints(Xbox1, 5, 0);

        TextField Xbox2 = new TextField();
        passInput.setPromptText("password");
        GridPane.setConstraints(Xbox2, 10, 0);

        button = new Button("click me");
        GridPane.setConstraints(button, 1, 2);
        button.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(passInput.getText()));

        button1 = new Button("click me for graph");
        GridPane.setConstraints(button1,100,50);
        button1.setOnAction(e->{

            GridPane grid1 = new GridPane();
            grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 100));
            grid.setVgap(8);
            java.awt.Button button = new java.awt.Button("hey click me");
            ChartViewer viewer = new ChartViewer(createChart());
            window.setScene(new Scene(viewer));
            Scene scene = new Scene(grid1, 300, 200);
            window.setTitle("VI Characteristics graph");
            window.setWidth(600);
            window.setHeight(400);
            window.show();
                });

        exitButton = new Button("Exit button");
        GridPane.setConstraints(exitButton, 10, 10);
        exitButton.setOnAction(e -> closeProgram());

        grid.getChildren().addAll(passInput,Xbox1,Xbox2, button,button1, exitButton, dropDown);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 200);

        ChartViewer viewer = new ChartViewer();
        //window.setScene();
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
    public static JFreeChart createChart() {


        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();

        XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Voltage");
        series1.add(10, 35);
        series1.add(11, 37);
        series1.add(12, 41);
        series1.add(12, 39);
        series1.add(13, 44);
        series1.add(14, 51);
        series1.add(15, 52);
        series1.add(15, 54);
        series1.add(16, 57);
        series1.add(17, 62);
        series1.add(17, 66);
        series1.add(18, 70);

        dataset.addSeries(series1);

        JFreeChart scatterPlot = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
                "VI Characteristics graph", // Chart title
                "Voltage", // X-Axis Label
                "Current", // Y-Axis Label
                dataset // Dataset for the Chart
        );
        return scatterPlot;
    }

    private static void closeProgram(){
        System.out.println("File saved");
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a exception?

Comment: not sure what that is but i dont think so

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `Main extends graph` instead of `Main extends Application`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very broad, but the basic approach is to update the underlying dataset—the listening chart will update itself in response. In the variation below, the <kbd>Add</kbd> button handler updates the class attribute [`series`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html) to add the values from a pair of [`Spinner`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,int,int)) instances.

```
series.add(xSpin.getValue(), ySpin.getValue());
```

Several related examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20ChartFactory.createScatterPlot%20add). Also consider adding a `ChartMouseListenerFX`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5C%5Bjfreechart%5D%20ChartMouseListenerFX), which will allow you to select points for editing. For reference, the pure JavaFX dynamic `BarChart` shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53579013/230513) employs the same concept: the animation's `KeyFrame` handler updates the `series`, and the listening chart updates itself in response.

```
series.getData().get(i).setYValue(pole[i]);
```

> how would I do this in terms of adding the points via a text field?

In this example, the easiest way is to invoke [`setEditable()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#setEditable(boolean)) on the spinners.

```
xSpin.setEditable(true);
ySpin.setEditable(true);
```

[image: Scatter Plot]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.fx.ChartViewer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/74182275/230513
 */
public class ScatterAdd extends Application {

    private final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Voltage");

    private JFreeChart createChart() {
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        series.add(10, 35);
        series.add(11, 37);
        series.add(12, 41);
        series.add(12, 39);
        series.add(13, 44);
        series.add(14, 51);
        series.add(15, 52);
        series.add(15, 54);
        series.add(16, 57);
        series.add(17, 62);
        series.add(17, 66);
        series.add(18, 70);
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        JFreeChart scatterPlot = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            "VI Characteristics", "Voltage", "Current", dataset
        );
        return scatterPlot;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("ScatterAdd");
        var xSpin = new Spinner<Number>(1, 100, 19, 1);
        var ySpin = new Spinner<Number>(1, 100, 67, 1);
        var button = new Button("Add");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                series.add(xSpin.getValue(), ySpin.getValue());
            }
        });
        var enter = new ToolBar(xSpin, ySpin, button);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        ChartViewer chartViewer = new ChartViewer(createChart());
        root.setCenter(chartViewer);
        root.setBottom(enter);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(enter, Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, how would i do this in terms of adding the points via a textfield.(Id just like an application that i type values into x and y boxes which plots them onto the graph.).Thanks

Comment: Going forward, that's a reasonable approach. You can replace the spinners with text fields, and the same approach will work. Now that you have a working [mre], please [edit] your question to reflect any problems you encounter.

Comment: Ive tried and ran the code youv'e created it works well thank you. just a question on what theese parameter values mean in this code  [var xSpin = new Spinner<Number>(1, 100, 19, 1);] as when i run the programme the value are in the spinner

Comment: @armitageshanks99 to understand the parameters to an API, always read the documentation, in this case the [Spinner constructor javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,int,int)).

Comment: @trashgod thanks for the code, How could i ammend this for the spinner to take decimal values. thank you

Comment: As @jewelsea rightly advises, use the API to select the [desired constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#%3Cinit%3E(double,double,double)); more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55427307/230513).

Comment: I've amended the spinner to take double values and it works thanks.