# How to makesure that my TableView updates with the questions I created

Tags: java, javafx

How to makesure that my `TableView` updates with the questions I created, with `TableView` showing the row of the question. I want to make sure that my `OpenEndedController` file adds in the question I created in my survey creator, in which the `TableView` in my `SurveyCreator.java` file should display the row with the question ID and question `Type`, but somehow it doesn't work. May someone help analyze it?

OpenEndedController.java file

```
package com.example.assignmentsurvey;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenEndedController {

    @FXML
    private TextArea AnswerField;

    @FXML
    private Button ExitOE;

    @FXML
    private TextField QuestionTitle;

    @FXML
    private Button addToTable;

    @FXML
    private TextField questionID;

    private String question;
    private String id;
    private String answer;
    public SurveyCreator surveyCreator;

    // initialize surveyCreator
    public OpenEndedController() {
        this.surveyCreator = new SurveyCreator();
    }

    @FXML
    void addOpenEnded(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Main add = new Main();
        try {
            // Get values from UI components`
            id = questionID.getText();
            question = QuestionTitle.getText();
            answer = AnswerField.getText();

            // Check if the title is not empty
            if (question.isEmpty()) {
                showAlert("Error", "Title cannot be empty.");
            } else {
                // Create Open-Ended question using the Question class
                Question openEndedQuestion = new Question(id,"Open-Ended", question, answer);
                 // Assuming you have a setAnswer method in your Question class

                // Add Open-Ended question to SurveyCreator
                if (surveyCreator != null) {
                    surveyCreator.addQuestion(openEndedQuestion);
                } else {
                    showAlert("Error", "SurveyCreator instance is null. Cannot add question.");
                    return;
                }

                // Clear the input fields
                clearFields();

                // Inform the user that the question was added
                showAlert("Success", "Open-Ended question added successfully!");

                // update tableview
                surveyCreator.updateTableView();

                // return to survey creator
                add.changeScene("surveycreator.fxml");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            showAlert("Error", "Please enter a valid numeric ID.");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void exitOpenEnded(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Main exit = new Main();
        exit.changeScene("surveycreator.fxml");
    }

    @FXML
    public void getAnswer(ActionEvent event) {
        AnswerField.getText();
    }

    @FXML
    public void getQuestionID(ActionEvent event) {
        String id = questionID.getText();
    }

    @FXML
    public void getQuestionTitle(ActionEvent event)  {
        QuestionTitle.getText();
    }


    private void showAlert(String title, String content) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setContentText(content);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    private void clearFields() {
        questionID.clear();
        QuestionTitle.clear();
        AnswerField.clear();
    }
}
```

SurveyCreator.java file:

```
package com.example.assignmentsurvey;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


import static javafx.application.Application.launch;

public class SurveyCreator implements Initializable {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    private String username;
    private String textArea;


    // Table
    @FXML
    public TableView<Question> showquestions;
    private ObservableList<Question> questionList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // Column
    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Question, String> ID;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Question, String> Type;


    @FXML
    private Button surveycreatorDelete;

    @FXML
    private Button surveycreatorEdit;

    @FXML
    private Button surveycreatorExit;

    @FXML
    private Button surveycreatorMCQ;

    @FXML
    private Button surveycreatorOpenEnded;

    @FXML
    private Button surveycreatorPublish;

    @FXML
    private Button surveycreatorRating;

    @FXML
    private Button surveycreatorSave;

    private Stage stage;

    private Question questionHandler = new Question();

    // update TableView
    public void updateTableView() {
        showquestions.getItems().clear();
        showquestions.getItems().addAll(questionList);
    }


    // add question
    public void addQuestion(Question question) {
        questionHandler.create(question);
        questionList.add(question);
        showquestions.setItems(questionList);
    }

    ObservableList<Question> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        ID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Question, String>("ID"));
        Type.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Question, String>("Type"));
    }

    // read question
    public Question getQuestionById(String targetID) {
        return questionHandler.read(targetID);
    }

    // update question
    public void updateQuestion(Question question) {
        questionHandler.update(question);
        showquestions.setItems(questionList);
    }

    // delete question
    public void deleteQuestion(String targetID) {
        questionHandler.delete(targetID);
        questionList.removeIf(q -> q.getId().equals(targetID));
        showquestions.setItems(questionList);
    }

    // initialize
    public SurveyCreator() {
        this.showquestions = new TableView<>();
        this.ID = new TableColumn<>();
        this.Type = new TableColumn<>();
        showquestions.setItems(questionList);
    }


    // load .csv file
    public void loadSurvey(File surveyFile) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(surveyFile))) {
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {


                String[] parts = line.split(",");

                // create question object
                Question newQuestion = new Question(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
                showquestions.getItems().add(newQuestion);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void exitSurveyCreator(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Main e = new Main();

        // get usernames from login check
        String adminUsername = LogIn.getAdminUsername();
        String userUsername = LogIn.getUserUsername();


        if (adminUsername != null && adminUsername.equals("admin")) {
            e.changeScene("adminpage.fxml");

        } else if (userUsername != null && userUsername.equals("user")) {
            e.changeScene("userpage.fxml");
        }
    }

    public void setDelete(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Question selectedQuestion = showquestions.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        // Check if item is selected
        if (selectedQuestion == null) {
           checkDelete(selectedQuestion.getId());
        }
    }

    private void checkDelete(String targetID) throws Exception {
        questionList.removeIf(q -> q.getId().equals(targetID));
        showquestions.setItems(questionList);
    }

    public void setEdit(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Question selectedQuestion = showquestions.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        // check if item is selected
        if (selectedQuestion != null) {
            navigateToScene(selectedQuestion);
        }
    }

    private void navigateToScene(Question question) throws Exception  {
        // initialize variables
        String Type = question.getType();
        String id = question.getId();

        switch (Type) {
            case "MCQ":
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MCQ.fxml"));
                break;
            case "Open-Ended":
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("open_ended.fxml"));
                break;
            case "Rating":
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("rating.fxml"));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setMCQ(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        checkMCQ();
    }

    private void checkMCQ() throws Exception {
        Main MCQ = new Main();
        MCQ.changeQuestion("MCQ.fxml");
    }

    public void setOpenEnded(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        openOpenEndedController();
    }

    private void openOpenEndedController() throws Exception {
        Main oe = new Main();
        oe.changeQuestion("open_ended.fxml");
    }

    public void setRating(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        checkRating();
    }

    private void checkRating() throws Exception {
        Main Rating = new Main();
        Rating.changeQuestion("rating.fxml");
    }

    public void setSave(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Main s = new Main();

        // get usernames
        String adminUsername = LogIn.getAdminUsername();
        String userUsername = LogIn.getUserUsername();

        // Save questions to CSV
        CSVHandler<Question> csvHandler = new CSVHandler<>("ID,Type,Title,Answer", ",", "\n");
        csvHandler.writeCSV(questionList, "survey1.csv", false);

        // save in this format
        fileChooser.setTitle("Save Survey");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Java Files", "*.java"));

        // show save dialog
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        // save function
        if (selectedFile != null) {
            try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(selectedFile);
                writer.write("public class Survey {/n/n}");

                // feature to return to pages
                if (adminUsername!= null && adminUsername.equals("admin")) {
                    s.changeScene("adminpage.fxml");
                    writer.close();
                }

                else if (userUsername != null && userUsername.equals("user")) {
                    s.changeScene("userpage.fxml");
                    writer.close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }


}
```

And for good measure, I have my UserPage.java file (basically a user interface for anyone who is logged in as a user, not admin)

UserPage.java:

```
package com.example.assignmentsurvey;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import static javafx.application.Application.launch;

public class UserPage {
    @FXML
    private Button logout;
    @FXML
    private Button addsurvey;
    @FXML
    private Button deletesurvey;
    @FXML
    private Button editsurvey;

    private static Stage stg;
    FileChooser fileChooser= new FileChooser();
    public void setLogout(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        checkLogout();
    }

    private void checkLogout() throws IOException {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.changeScene("logintest.fxml");
    }

    // connected to a button in the userpage.fxml file
    public void setAdd(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        addSurvey();
    }

    // the function to create a new survey file
    private void addSurvey() {
        // set directory of where to save the file
        File defaultDirectory = new File("C:\\Users\\adruc\\IdeaProjects\\assignmentsurvey\\src\\main\\java\\com\\example\\Surveys");
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(defaultDirectory);

        // set the upper title of the dialog
        fileChooser.setTitle("Add File");

        // show open file dialog name the newly created file
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "*.csv"));
        java.io.File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (selectedFile != null) {
            // name the file
            try {
                String fileName = selectedFile.getName();
                if (!fileName.endsWith(".csv")) {
                    fileName += ".csv";
                }
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(selectedFile.getParent() + "/" + fileName);
                writer.write("public class Survey {\n\n}");
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setDelete(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        deleteSurvey();
    }

    private void deleteSurvey() throws IOException {
        fileChooser.setTitle("Delete File");

        // show open file dialog
        java.io.File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stg);

        if (selectedFile != null) {
            boolean result = selectedFile.delete();

            if (result) {
                Alert alert1 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                alert1.setTitle("File deleted");
                alert1.setHeaderText("Success!");
                alert1.setContentText("File has been successfully deleted.");

            }
            else {
                Alert alert2 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert2.setTitle("Error");
                alert2.setHeaderText("Error");
                alert2.setContentText("There was an issue trying to delete the file.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void setEdit(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        editSurvey();
    }

    private void editSurvey() throws IOException {
        // set initial directory
        File defaultDirectory = new File("C:\\Users\\adruc\\IdeaProjects\\assignmentsurvey\\src\\main\\java\\com\\example\\Surveys");
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(defaultDirectory);
        fileChooser.setTitle("Edit File");

        // show open dialog
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "*.csv"));
        java.io.File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        // select the file
        if (selectedFile != null) {
            try {
                Main edit = new Main();
                edit.changeQuestion("surveycreator.fxml");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

I do have some other files, such as Main.java:

```
package com.example.assignmentsurvey;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static Stage stg;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        stg = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("logintest.fxml")));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void changeScene(String fxml) throws IOException {
        Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource(fxml)));
        stg.getScene().setRoot(pane);
    }

    public void changeQuestion(String fxml) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource(fxml)));
        stg.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 650));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

CSVHandler.java:

```
package com.example.assignmentsurvey;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.*;



public class CSVHandler <T>{
    private String delimiter = ",";
    private String newline = "\n";
    private String header;

    public CSVHandler(String header, String delimiter, String newline) {
        this.header = header;
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
        this.newline = newline;
    }

    public void writeCSV(List<T> data, String fileName, boolean append) {
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, append);
            if (!append) {
                fileWriter.append(header);
                fileWriter.append(newline);
            }
            for (T element : data) {
                // int rows = data.size();
                Field[] fields = element.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                int discard = 0;
                for (Field f : fields) {
                    // get rid of public var, which are shared variables
                    if (Modifier.isPublic(f.getModifiers())) {
                        discard += 1;
                    }
                }
                int columns = fields.length - discard;
                int count = 0;
                for (Field f : fields) {
                    // only list private variables internal to a class
                    if (Modifier.isPrivate(f.getModifiers())) {
                        count += 1;
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        fileWriter.append(f.get(element).toString());
                        if (count % columns != 0) {
                            fileWriter.append(delimiter);
                        }
                    }
                }
                fileWriter.append(newline);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<T> readCSV(String fileName, CSVParser<T> parser) {
        BufferedReader bReader = null;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                String line = "";
                bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                bReader.readLine();

                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    T element = parser.parseLine(line.split(delimiter));
                    if (element != null)
                        data.add(element);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bReader != null)
                        bReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public List<UserDetails> readJSON(String fileName, Class<UserDetails[]> clazz) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<UserDetails> data = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                data = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(file, clazz));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the model, your `ObservableList`, and the view, your `TableView`, will update itself in response. If a problem remains, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that illustrates the problem you encounter. See also [Why should I avoid using PropertyValueFactory in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437983/230513)

Comment: The recommended way to do this is to use a [MVC-type approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx). If you don’t want to do that, and want to keep the data in the controller, then you need to call `addQuestion(…)` on the actual controller.

Comment: Also note that your `updateTableView()` method doesn’t do what you want.  `showQuestions.getItems()` returns `questionList` (since you previously call `showQuestions.setItems(questionList)`), so `showQuestions.getItems().clear()` results both in `questionList` being empty and the table having no data to display. Then `showQuestions.getItems().addAll(questionList)` is a no-op (add no items to the list) and the table will be empty. The method is completely redundant anyway: remove it all all calls to it.

Comment: Maybe if I gave you the package you can take a look I guess? Here's the link to the package from my Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1byC7ShScYWKRslLn2lm-fybWLKtosX25/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What’s wrong with the suggestions I already made?

Comment: First, study the problem in isolation, perhaps using this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76497248/230513).

Comment: It is (almost) always wrong to instantiate a class you are using as a controller for an FXML file. It is absolutely always wrong to instantiate fields that are annotated `@FXML`: the annotation explicitly says the fields are intended to be initialized by the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: @James_D's observation is examined in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77546686/230513).

Comment: *"Here's the link to the package from my Google Drive"* -> That is not [the way this site is supposed to work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359303/providing-a-github-url-in-questions).  Questions should be self-contained  - and it may require work to be able to do that and create a requested [mcve] or similar example, but, so be it.